# Make an element's height match another element's height, whose height is smaller (JS, Bootstrap, React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make an element's (elementMain) height match another element's (elementSecondary) height, which height is not a statically set value. I use both React and Bootstrap, I want to know if there is a more clean approach than using pure JS.

```
<div className='row text-primary d-flex'>
    <div className="col" id="mainElement">...SOME TEXT..</div>
    <aside className="col overflow-auto" id="secondaryElement">...SOME IMAGES...</div>
</div>
```

I should specify that the height of the primary element is smaller than the secondary one.

Comment: Bro i am not sure about this issue.. but if you want same height horizontally, then you can use style **display: inline-flex**

Comment: Tiwari assume that this will take the height of the tallest element though right?

Comment: yes bro, you have to set style in your parent div so it will inherit display-flex as well.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to match the height of the shorter element. I forgot to mention it. Sorry I specified it now in the question as well.